# Observing rspec error

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am currently getting the following output while executing the following rspec command:

```
MacBook-Pro:01_temperature fr$ gem install rspec
Successfully installed rspec-2.14.1
Parsing documentation for rspec-2.14.1
Done installing documentation for rspec after 0 seconds
1 gem installed

MacBook-Pro:01_temperature fr$ rspec --init
  create   spec/spec_helper.rb
  create   .rspec

MacBook-Pro:01_temperature fr$ rspec temperature_spec.rb 
/Users/fr/Downloads/learn_ruby-master/01_temperature/temperature_spec.rb:18:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /Users/fr/Downloads/learn_ruby-master/01_temperature/temperature (LoadError)
    from /Users/fr/Downloads/learn_ruby-master/01_temperature/temperature_spec.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load'
    from /Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
    from /Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Please see the source code for the file temperature_spec.rb

```
require "temperature"

describe "temperature conversion functions" do

  describe "#ftoc" do

    it "converts freezing temperature" do
      ftoc(32).should == 0
    end

    it "converts boiling temperature" do
      ftoc(212).should == 100
    end

    it "converts body temperature" do
      ftoc(98.6).should == 37
    end

    it "converts arbitrary temperature" do
      ftoc(68).should == 20
    end

  end

  describe "#ctof" do

    it "converts freezing temperature" do
      ctof(0).should == 32
    end

    it "converts boiling temperature" do
      ctof(100).should == 212
    end

    it "converts arbitrary temperature" do
      ctof(20).should == 68
    end

    it "converts body temperature" do
      ctof(37).should be_within(0.1).of(98.6)
      # Why do we need to use be_within?
      # See http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/169330
      # and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008
      # and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format
      # Also, try "puts 0.5 - 0.4 - 0.1" -- pretty crazy, right?
    end

  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that you don't have a file by the name of `temperature.rb` in the same directory as your `temperature_spec.rb` file.

Comment: Hi Peter, I managed to get it fixed. The file temperature.rb was present in the same directory. However, I was still receiving the error message.

Upon editing the line **require "temperature"** to **'require_relative "temperature"'** the problem got fixed.